# Receive all available messages from a ZeroMQ (pyzmq) socket

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

Is there a nice way to receive all messages available messages on a zmq socket? Particularly when using a Poller.

Or is the only solution to keep calling a non blocking `recv()` and until theres nothing left?

Edit :

I think I might have answered my own questions. Using `socket.poll()` is the cleanest I can see.

```
import zmq

ctx = zmq.Context.instance()
socket = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:1234')
socket.subscribe = ''

messages = []
while socket.poll(100) == zmq.POLLIN:
    messages.append(socket.recv())

print messages
```

Comment: What's wrong with calling `recv()` repeatedly?

Comment: If you check [the documentation](http://zeromq.github.io/pyzmq/api/zmq.html#zmq.Socket.recv), you'll see `recv` supports non-blocking operation

Answer (score 0):

Probably worth mentioning that if message volumes are high, you can drop the `socket.poll` timeout to `0` so that it returns immediately - more [here](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-poll).